# Can I use an Azure SQL Database as the source for a replication publication?

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-replication, azure-sql-managed-instance

Due to *reasons* (I've been told it's a networking issue with MIs; regardless, we can't fix it, we're waiting on a solution from MS that may or may not come out this year), we cannot talk from on-prem to managed instances.  However, we can reach Azure SQL Databases.

We would like to replicate lookup data from on-prem to Azure Managed Instances (MIs) as well as ASDs.  Is there any way to use the ASD as a "jump" box for replication, maybe by putting the Distributor on an MI that can talk to the ASD?

Looked at Azure Data Sync, but the 5-minute-minimum makes it a no-go.

Otherwise, our current fallback is to run an Azure VM/AKS instance, replicate to it, then from there to the ASDs/MIs.  But man, I'd rather not have to do that.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[One Way Transactional replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/migrate-to-database-from-sql-server#method-2-use-transactional-replication) using SQL Data Sync for Azure.
If they wish to maintain the replication running after the migration to Managed Instances, transactional replication will be the best option at this time. Replication to Azure SQL Database

Or using ETL via Azure DataFactory

Transfer data from a SQL Server database to an Azure SQL Database using Azure Blob Storage and the Azure Data Factory (ADF): this is a supported legacy technique that benefits from a replicated staging copy.
ADF pipeline consisting of two data migration processes. They work together to transfer data between a SQL Server database and an Azure SQL Database on a regular basis. The two actions are as follows:
Data should be copied from a SQL Server database to an Azure Blob Storage account